# nginx post_action proxy_pass rewrite

Tags: post, nginx, url-rewriting, action, proxypass

I rewrite download urls with the rewrite url below.
No I want to count the downloads and want to use post_action from nginx.

```
    location / {        
            rewrite_log on;
            rewrite "^/download/([^/]+)/$" /download.php?key=$1 break;
     }

    location /download/ {
            post_action @countdownload;
    }

    location @countdownload {
            internal;
            proxy_pass http://subdomain.example.com/count.php;
    }
```

I have read some articles that i have to use break statement instead of last. I tried that but I get an error:

> "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in ....

I followed this tutorial http://www.tipstuff.org/2012/08/Nginx-post-action-to-trigger-successfully-download-file.html
What am I doing wrong?